# IntelliJ IDEA Android SQLite Data Source Synchronisation Error: File exists

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I am trying to connect to `SQLite database` on my android phone through `Database` tool window. I have created an `SQLite` data source for my database and can view my `schemas`, execute queries etc.

The problem occurs when i try to upload the `modified database.`

This is the error message i get when `uploading the database`.

[image]

IntelliJ IDEA Version:
[image]

OS: mac OS X El Capitan

I am using non-rooted Android 6.0 device

It used to work on previous `IntelliJ` versions but now it is not working. I cannot find help on this matter anywhere on the internet. Any help will be much `appreciated`. Thanks